# How to use run time error in golang?

Tags: http, go, runtime

I am trying to download something from 3 servers. My idea is if the first server is closed,it will use the second server. I noticed,if the first server has been closed, it will created a run time error.I want to know how to use this error,what i need is like this:

```
if run time err!=nil{do something}
```

i am new to golang,hope someone can help me
thank you

Comment: Post your code so we can understand your problem/partial solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To elaborate on what FUZxxl explained, go makes a distinction between an *error* (something which could go wrong indeed went wrong) and an *exception* (something which could not possibly go wrong actually went wrong).

The distinction can sometimes be subtle (as it relies on what is 'unexpected'), but it can also be clearer than the 'everything is an exception' that you see in other languages.

For instance, consider integers which might overflow. One possibility is to consider it a 'normal' behaviour, which should be handled appropriately:

```
func safe_add(x, y uint32) (uint32, error) {
    z := x + y
    if z < x || z < y {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Integer overflow")
    }
    return z, nil
}
```

Another is to consider it 'never happens' and have the runtime `panic` in the unlikely case when it happens against all odds:

```
func panic_add(x, y uint32) uint32 {
    z, err := safe_add(x, y)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return z
}
```

(Note that I use my own 'safe_add' here, but you don't have to of course)

The main difference is in the way you handle the error afterwards. Adding a number to itself until it overflows with `error`s gives:

```
func safeloop(u uint32) {
    var err error
    for {
        if u, err = safe_add(u, u); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println(u)
        }
    }
}
```

While handling panics uses the `recover` built-in function:

```
func panicloop(u uint32) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()
    for {
        u = panic_add(u, u)
        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}
```

(full examples on [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/hXczoXf5Zy))

Note that the panic version has a much simpler loop, as you basically never expect anything to go wrong and never check for errors. The counterpart for this is that the way to handle panics is quite cumbersome, even for a very simple example like this. You `defer` a function which will call `recover` and capture the error when it arises and breaks out of the function. When your code becomes more complex, tracking exactly where/how the panic arose and acting on it accordingly can become *much* more complex than checking for errors in places where they could arise, with the `result, err := func_which_may_fail(...)` pattern.

You can even alternate between panics, recover which return errors, errors converted to panics, ... but this is (understandably) considered poor design.

There are some good resources on [error handling](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) and [panics](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) on the go blog. The [specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors) is a good read to.

In your case, as you expect 'the server is closed' to be a pretty frequent behaviour, you should definitely go the `error` way, as FUZxxl suggested, but I hope this might be useful to you (or others) to understand how error handling works in Go.

Answer (score 1):

When you do something which could go wrong, you get an `error` object.

```
bytes, err = stream.Read(buffer)
```

To check whether what you tried actually went wrong, compare the `error` object against `nil`. `nil` signalizes that no error has happened. In the case the error is not `nil`, you can do something about it.

```
if err != nil {
    // insert error handling here
}
```

Comment: if the server is shut down, i will not catch the err

Comment: after i tried, i found out  recover is very useful. thanks any way

Comment: @user2981682 If the server is shutdown, even recover won't catch the error because the program doesn't exist anymore.